# Set Thread page Priority to Low in C# for better Memory Mapped File handling

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

In C# during heavy read/write I/O using a Memory Mapped File, the system significantly lags.

I've read that changing the page proirity for a thread may help the situation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn567645(v=vs.85).aspx

> An alternative solution for the app vendor might be to use low memory
>   priority when accessing the files. This can be achieved using the
>   SetThreadInformation API. Pages that are accessed at low memory
>   priority are removed from the working set more aggressively.

How is this done in C#?

Comment: I guess you have to pinvoke into those winapi functions yourself (first obtaining handle for the current thread). But note that in theory .NET thread might not have 1-to-1 correspondance with native OS thread (though as I understand - in practice it has): https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md

Comment: This doesn't make sense, mmfs are written very lazily.  Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  If you constantly create new views on the mmf at different offsets then don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant, the anti-malware / windows defender is off. The problem occurs when the view size is bigger than physical memory while doing random I/O on the view. The system keeps a lot of recently used pages in the cache presumable as read cache. Since I'm mapping a huge file I want it to evict those pages from memory more aggressively (or immediately) to have memory availability for other tasks on the system.